# JSF OnClick commandbutton

Tags: javascript, jsf, onclick

How do I use Javascript to "click" on a CommandButton?

I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
<ice:panelTab id="searchResultsTab" label="Search Results" onclick="document.getElementById('form:searchTabs:0:refreshButton').click();">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either the element ID is wrong, or the `ice:panelTab` itself is doing something during `onclick` as well which has overriden your `onclick`, or the HTML rendering went bogus (this can happen in one very specific situation) and the `onclick` attribute has never been rendered to the response.

To fix the first, doublecheck the page source. To fix the second, check the page source if that is indeed the case  and then add a `return false;` to end of the `onclick`. To fix the third, you'll first need to confirm that the `onclick` is indeed not there in the HTML output and then tell more about JSF API and impl versions.

All with all, the answer is in the generated HTML output. It's also the running context of Javascript.

Comment: Strange...I've double checked the ID but it doesnt seem to work...If I move the commandButton out of the panelTabSet and change the Id to form:refreshButton it does work...is this some AJAX issue? Cant see how to access it.

Comment: Sorry, since I don't do IceFaces, I can't tell from head how it is supposed to behave and generate HTML. Just check and debug the generated HTML/JS source. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) is very helpful here.